# Spring Boot "SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()" returns the wrong credentials

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt, credentials, security-context

I'm building a Spring Boot webapp, and I've encountered a problem. Whenever I first log in with a user I'm still getting that user's credentials with the SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() method, even after logging out with the first user and logging in with another.

For example, if I log in with the "admin" user, and I log out, and I log back in with "viewer", I still get the credentials for "admin", and I have to refresh the page to stop this behavior.

And the interesting part is that when logging in, I get the correct credentials in the AuthenticationController class generateToken method log.info("user has just logged in: " + authentication.getName()); line, this weird behavior only applies when calling the SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() method.

My AuthenticationController (please pay attention to my comments, it includes stuff I've tried already)

```
package com.issue.tracker.authentication;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final TokenService tokenService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> generateToken(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        //SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        //^Including this clearContext() method doesn't seem to do anything, anywhere at all.

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginRequest.username(),
                        loginRequest.password());

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);

        if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            log.info("user has just logged in: " + authentication.getName());
            //I get the correct credentials here every single time!
        }

        String token = tokenService.generateToken(authentication);

        List<String> roles = authentication.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).toList();

        //SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        //^I thought this would do something, but nothing, same behavior...

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new LoginResponse(token, roles));
    }

    @PostMapping("/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        /*
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null) {
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, authentication);
        }
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        */
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        //Probably nothing wrong with my logout method either, including the above commented out code doesn't do anything either
    }
}
```

My SecurityConfig:

```
package com.issue.tracker.authentication;

import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.UUID;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableMethodSecurity
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorAware")
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .headers(header -> header.frameOptions().sameOrigin())
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                        })
                )
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey());
        return (((jwkSelector, securityContext)
                -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet)));
    }

    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() throws JOSEException {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaKey().toRSAPublicKey()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("");

        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public RSAKey rsaKey() {

        KeyPair keyPair = keyPair();

        return new RSAKey
                .Builder((RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic())
                .privateKey((RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate())
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public KeyPair keyPair() {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("RSA Key Pair can not be generated!", e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorAware() {
        return new CustomAuditAware();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource
                = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

My AuthenticationServiceImpl:

```
package com.issue.tracker.common;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements AuthenticationService {

    @Override
    public Authentication getAuthentication() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        log.info("USERNAME: "+authentication.getName()); //Wrong credentials here, it retains the first logged in user's info every single time...
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

Everything I've tried so far is included in the AuthenticationController comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing worked therefore I just solved it with forcing page refresh upon logging out on the frontend. (`window.location.reload(true)`);